# How to display something once after a specific check in the templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

I need this principle to work:

```
{% for a in activites %}
    {% if not a.is_on_top %}
        {% if not "form is displayed" %} <- how to do this?
            Display the form
            {% assign a boolean "form is displayed" %} <- how to do this?
        {% endif %}
    {% else %}
        display a lot of stuff
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with vanilla tags (but I would be happy proved otherwise):

> If you have a background in programming, or if you’re used to
>   languages which mix programming code directly into HTML, you’ll want
>   to bear in mind that the Django template system is not simply Python
>   embedded into HTML. This is by design: the template system is meant to
>   express presentation, **not program logic**.

However you can use custom `{% assign [name] [value] %}` tag:

```
from django import template

class AssignNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

    def render(self, context):
        context[self.name] = self.value.resolve(context, True)
        return ''

def do_assign(parser, token):
    """
    Assign an expression to a variable in the current context.

    Syntax::
        {% assign [name] [value] %}
    Example::
        {% assign list entry.get_related %}

    """
    bits = token.contents.split()
    if len(bits) != 3:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError("'%s' tag takes two arguments" % bits[0])
    value = parser.compile_filter(bits[2])
    return AssignNode(bits[1], value)

register = template.Library()
register.tag('assign', do_assign)
```

(Taken form [here](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/539/))

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/) is Django's doc on custom tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this logic via variable `forloop.first`, which available in for loop.

For example:

```
{% if forloop.first %}
    Display the form
{% endif %}
```

Comment: It's not only the first element, it's a condition that may not be true after the n-th element